# Determining all legal hands of cards based off a given hand (Big 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, playing-cards

So, I've been trying to code a function that will rank all card combinations in a hands in the card game **Big 2**.

In this game, the suit order is: `Diamonds --> Clubs --> Hearts --> Spades`

A hand will generally look like this:

```
hand = ['3D', '4D', '4H', '7D', '8D', '8H', '0D', '0C', 'JH', 'QC', 'QS', 'KH', 'AS']
```

After making all possible pairs, triples and singles, I rank them using this function:

```
rank = {}
suits = {}
count = 3 
suit = 0

for i in "34567890JQKA2":
  rank[i] = count
  count += 1

for i in "DCHS":
  suits[i] = suit
  suit += 2


def percentileCalc(card_input, pair):
  n = 0
  if pair:
    for card in card_input:
      if "S" in card:
        n = 4    
    card = card_input[0]
  else:
    n = suits[card_input[1]]
    card = card_input
  percentile = math.floor(8 * (rank[card[0]] - 3) +  n)
  return percentile


def all_pairs(hand):
  pairs = []
  for i in itertools.combinations(hand, 2):
    result = is_pair(i[0], i[1])
    if result:
      pairs.append(list(i))
  return pairs

def all_triples(hand):
  triples = []
  for i in itertools.combinations(hand, 3):
    result = is_triple(i[0], i[1], i[2])
    if result:
      triples.append(list(i))
  return triples


def buildHand(hand):
  tempList = []
  pairs = ES.all_pairs(hand)
  triples = ES.all_triples(hand)
  final = []
  for select in triples:
      percentile = percentileCalc(select, True)
      tempList.append([3, percentile, select])
  for selection in pairs:
      percentile = percentileCalc(selection, True)
      tempList.append([2, percentile, selection])
  for card in hand:
      percentile = percentileCalc(card, False)
      tempList.append([1, percentile, [card]])
  tempList.sort(key=lambda x : x[1], reverse=True)
  return tempList
```

As you can see, buildHand returns a list of all possible card combinations my hand could possess and they are ranked accordingly.

However, when I try to build a further function to construct all possible legal hands (no repeating cards/combinations) and compare their percentiles together, I end up with an amalgamation that can't give the correct amount of cards back, nor any legal hands.

I know the function is terrible, but I have no idea how to do this (assuming it's possible).

The current function is:

```
def constructor(combinations):
  allHands = []
  for comb in itertools.combination(combinations, 13):
    comb = list(comb)
    for i in comb:
      card = i[1]
      for permutes in comb:
        if card in permutes:
          comb.delete(permutes)
    allHands.append(comb) 
  return allHands
```

Few problems with this function:

1. It does not count the amount of cards (that being hand size which can be represented as `hand_sizes`,) which leads to too many cards
2. It doesn't accurately delete all duplicate card combos such as:

   ```
   [["AS", "AH"], ["AS", "AC"]]
   ```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: It might help if you told us what game you're talking about.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I forgot. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I'm confused. Where is `hand_sizes` in your code? What do you mean by "duplicate card combos" -- `itertools.combinations` does not give you any duplicates. if `combinations` is the list of all cards in your deck, then `itertools.combinations(combinations, 13)` is the list of all 13 card hands available from that deck.

Comment: Also possibly useful to know is that the number of valid orderings of a 52 card deck is on the order of 8e67. Far and beyond anything you could remotely hope to hold in memory. You cannot possibly enumerate all possible games of Big Two, nor is it clear why you'd want to.